# how to rename files in a pair with a script

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I have 10 pdf files in a folder and im trying to find a way to rename them as pairs using a script for it to look like something like this

```
file131.pdf = order_receipt_1000.pdf
file304.pdf = invoice_1000.pdf
file542.pdf = order_receipt_1001.pdf
file194.pdf = invoice_1001.pdf
```

and so on for the next 8 ones

Comment: What's the relationship between the original names and the new ones? Why are `file131.pdf` and `file304.pdf` a pair?

Comment: there isn't really a relationship, they are just in the same directory, they're in this order because I sorted the files by LastWriteTime. Im not sure if they have to be a pair, I just want to rename 2 files into an order receipt and invoice that have the same number starting from 1000 incrementing by 1 each time 2 files have been renamed (sorry if this is confusing lol)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this gives you a good starting point. The language is Autoit. ([www.autoitscript.com](http://www.autoitscript.com))

Currently the script looks into the folder where it is saved for *pdf files. Then an new array with the files found is created an the second column contains the time when the file has been created. After that the last For-loop renames the files in chunks of two files each.

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    Local $aFileList = _FileListToArray(@ScriptDir, '*.pdf', Default, True) ; change @scriptDir to the path you need
    If @error = 1 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Path was invalid.")
        Exit
    EndIf
    If @error = 4 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "No file(s) were found.")
        Exit
    EndIf

    _ArrayDisplay($aFileList, "Files FOUND")

    Local $a[UBound($aFileList)][2]

    For $i = 0 To UBound($aFileList) - 1
        $a[$i][0] = $aFileList[$i]
        $a[$i][1] = FileGetTime($aFileList[$i], $FT_CREATED, $FT_STRING) ; change FT_CREATED to what you need (created, modified, ...)
    Next

    _ArraySort($a, 0, 0, 0, 1)

    _ArrayDisplay($a, "Sorted FileList")
    Local $startcount = 1000, $y = 0

    For $i = 1 To UBound($a) - 1 Step 2
        FileMove($a[$i][0], 'order_receipt_' & $startcount + $y & '.pdf')
        FileMove($a[$i + 1][0], 'invoice_' & $startcount + $y & '.pdf')
        $y += 1
    Next
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```